# How can I set up merchant only with PayPal email?

Tags: reactjs, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I've some question about PayPal merchant

1. If I understand correctly the payee inside PayPalButton is where you actually hand over the money to the merchant. So where for is the merchant-id in the PayPalScriptProvider  options?
2. What would happen if I leave PayPalScriptProvider options merchant-id and only use the payee
3. I can use payee with email_address: 'MERCHANT_EMAIL' due to the paypal documentation. What is the equivalent for the PayPalScriptProvider options merchant-id.
4. Can every PayPal Account private / business use only email address as merchant-id (email_address) inside the payee object?

```
const initialOptions = {
  'client-id': 'MY_CLIENT_ID'
  'merchant-id': 'MERCHANT_ID',

  // EMAIL only possible?

  components: 'buttons',
  'data-namespace': 'PayPalSDK',
  currency: 'EUR',
  intent: 'capture',
  'enable-funding': ['sofort', 'giropay'],
  'disable-funding': ['card', 'sepa'],
};

PayPalScriptProvider options={initialOptions}
```

Inside my PayPalButton:

```
payee: {
  merchant_id: 'MERCHANT_ID'
  //email_address: 'MERCHANT_EMAIL',
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Set payee.email_address in the PayPalButton. Do not set merchant-id in the script options.